# Correct syntax for creating an array from a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query which gives me values per day, however I've had to hardcode it as I can't work out how to change it into a loop:

```
var result = from c in groupedJobs

    select new
    {
        Name = c,
        Data = new int[] {
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[0]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[1]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[2]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[3]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[4]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[5]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[6]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[7]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[8]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[9]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[10]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[11]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[12]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[13]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[14]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[15]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[16]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[17]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[18]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[19]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[20]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[21]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[22]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[23]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[24]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[25]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[26]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[27]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[28]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[29]),
        groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[30]),

    }
    };
```

I'm trying to do something like this but the syntax is wrong:

```
select new ClaimProviderCountAggregate
{
    Name = c,
    Data = new int[] {
        foreach (var item in daysInMonth)
        {
            groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==item
        }
```

More info:

Days is an array for the number of days in the current month

```
 var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
 var days = Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth).ToArray();
```

This is my definition for groupedjobs

```
var groupedJobs = new List<ClaimProviderCount>();
public class ClaimProviderCount
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string ClaimProvider { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A question now that you've put in more details. Are you sure this is what you want? In your anonymous object `c` (and hence `Name`) is not going to be a string, yet you are comparing it with one. I think what you want is `Name = c.ClaimProvider`. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, considering your `days` is an enumerable:

```
from c in groupedJobs
select new
{
    Name = c,
    Data = days.Select(day => groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==day))
               .ToArray()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object first:

```
var a=select new ClaimProviderCountAggregate
{
    Name = c,
    Data = new int[30]
}
```

Then populate the array with loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<31;i++)
        {
            a.Data[i++]=groupedJobs.Count(d => d.ClaimProvider == c && d.Date.Day==days[i])
        }
```